# Strange RotateTowards issue in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am writing a simple game in Unity 3D with C# as a scripting language. I need to rotate the camera around 180 degrees. The strange thing is the first call of **Quarterion.RotateTowards** works, while the other one doesn't, although it should be just a reference to the same object.

```
public class ChangeCamera : MonoBehaviour {

Quaternion firstMinionCameraRot, secondMinionCameraRot;

Quaternion newRot; 

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Quaternion firstMinionCameraRot = new Quaternion(0.0f, 1.0f, -0.3f, 0.0f);
    Quaternion secondMinionCameraRot = new Quaternion(-0.3f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
} 

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    newRot = this.transform.rotation;

    // This one works 
    newRot = Quaternion.RotateTowards(newRot, new Quaternion(-0.3f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), 0.05f * Time.deltaTime);
    // This one doesn't 
    newRot = Quaternion.RotateTowards(newRot, secondMinionCameraRot, 50.0f * Time.deltaTime);

    newRot = this.transform.rotation;
 }
```

**EDIT: 
I am doing the final assignment newRot = this.transform.rotation; I missed this line when preparing the code snippet. When I am using the second option (where the Quaterion was initialized in the begining, no exception is being thrown, it just does not perform any rotation).**

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Is it throwing an exception? As your code is written, nothing is being done with the Quaternion newRot that is being returned. If you want the RotateTowards method to perform a behavior on an object, you would assign the return value to a transform.rotation. In other words, you are missing  myGameObject.transform.rotation = newRot;

Comment: do not use quaternions for any reason.  simply use `Rotate` (or perhaps `RotateAround`)  one of the most ridiculous things about Unity is that they mention "quaternions" in the manual. they are totally irrelevant to everything. if you want to rotate something, use `Rotate`

Comment: [This answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/115691/unity-camera-tilt/115693#115693) may helps you

Comment: @HBomb And I am doing this assignment: myGameObject.transform.rotation = newRot; 
Just forgot to add it to my snippet. This is not the reason of this problem.
The rotation is just not performed in the second case. No exception is being thrown

Comment: @PawełJastrzębski - you ***rarely use 'quaternions' for any reason - ever***.  It is one of the most confused things in Unity - it's a great pity they ever mentioned it in the manual.  All you do is use **Rotate** or **RotateAround**.  It's really that simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i) You are not initializing your variables correctly. You are hiding the two variables you intend to work on.

```
Quaternion firstMinionCameraRot, secondMinionCameraRot;
void Start () {
    firstMinionCameraRot = new Quaternion(0.0f, 1.0f, -0.3f, 0.0f);
    secondMinionCameraRot = new Quaternion(-0.3f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
}
```

ii) As @HBomb mentionned, set your rotation back on your game object.

```
void Update () {
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, secondMinionCameraRot, 50.0f * Time.deltaTime);
 }
```

NOTE: Quaternion is a struct thus it is passed by value. You cannot expect to work on a reference to your game object's rotation like you appear to be doing with the "newRot" variable.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am assinging back the value to the newRot (see the updated code). That was not the case.

Comment: @PawełJastrzębski okay, but you are still hiding the Quaternion structs in Start. You dont assign new value to the global field but to local variable of Start method.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski The secondMinionCameraRot is defined in the body of the class. Start() method is invoked in the begining, so it calls the constructor. I don't get the point of hiding the value.